# NOT IN operator of SQL equivalent in php

Tags: php, sql, operators

Is there an equivalent of NOT IN operator on SQL in PHP?

```
if(count($result1) > 0) {
    $query_transline_conflict = "SELECT * FROM transaction_line as tl LEFT JOIN transaction as t ON tl.transaction_id = t.transaction_id LEFT JOIN resources as r ON tl.resource_id = r.resource_id WHERE t.equipment_class_id = '$equipment_class_id' AND tl.returned = '0'";
    $result_transline_conflict = mysqli_query($conn, $query_transline_conflict);
    $result2 = mysqli_fetch_all($result_transline_conflict,MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
    $x = 0;
       foreach($result2 as $row){
         $already_booked_range = getDatesFromRange($row['start_date'],$row['end_date']);
         $new_array_already_booked[$x] = $already_booked_range;
         $x++;
  }
```

I have a start_date and end_date that is being input. now the `$new_array_already_booked` stores the range of the date that will be compared. so i want to use NOT IN operator for php to compare. I hope im making sense. still a beginner and trying to learn.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2019-07-25
        [1] => 2019-07-26
        [2] => 2019-07-27
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2019-07-30
        [1] => 2019-07-31
        [2] => 2019-08-01
    )

)
```

Comment: Show some code of what you're trying to attempt.

Comment: Not IN ..  .. where  .. in PHP array??

Comment: @scaisEdge yes in php array.

Comment: @aynber i will post the code one moment

Answer (score 2):

for check if an element is  in an array you can use `in_array()`

```
$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
if (in_array("Irix", $os)) {
    echo "Got Irix";
}
if (in_array("mac", $os)) {
    echo "Got mac";
}
```

for NOT IN you can use `!in_array()`

```
$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
if (!in_array("MyValue", $os)) {
    echo "MyValue not in array";
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if any elements of one array are in another, you can use `array_intersect`:

```
$a = Array('bird', 'butterfly', 'bat');
$b = Array('ball', 'helmet', 'bat');

if (!array_intersect($a, $b)) echo 'not in';
```